# Probability that at least one person has a disease

Tags: probability

Let's say there are 5 different diseases; 1/100 people have one of these five diseases.

Just to be clear, what I means is: 1/100 people have the first disease, 1/100 people have the second disease, 1/100 people have the third disease, 1/100 people have the fourth disease, and 1/100 people have the fifth disease.

If you have a group of 500 randomly selected individuals, what is the probability that at least one person has one of the five diseases?

The way I understand it, since there are 5 diseases each with 1/100 probability, then 5/100 people have one of these diseases.. So, if you have 500 people, the probability that someone has the disease would be 500*(5/100) = 25. But this makes no sense! What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

EDIT: A person cannot have more than one of the five diseases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few important assumptions in the statement of the problem.  If it turns out that the probability of getting each disease individually are dependent and not mutually exclusive, then there is not enough information to solve.

If you are not able to be sick with two diseases simultaneously (the diseases are mutually exclusive), then 5 in 100 people will be sick on average (with exactly one disease).  Out of 500 people, the probability that at least one person is sick is opposite the probability that none of them are sick.

The probability none are sick is: $\binom{500}{0}(\frac{95}{100})^{500}(\frac{5}{100})^0 = (\frac{95}{100})^{500}$, so the probability at least one is sick is $1 - (\frac{95}{100})^{500}$

---

The other possible interpretation of the problem is that it *is* possible to get multiple diseases at once, and the chances of doing so are independent of one another.  The chance someone is healthy then is $(\frac{99}{100})^5$.

So, the probability none are sick is $\binom{500}{0}((\frac{99}{100})^{5})^{500}((\frac{1}{100})^{5})^{0} = ((\frac{99}{100})^{5})^{500}$

Thus, the probability that at least one is sick is $1-((\frac{99}{100})^{5})^{500}$

Answer (score 1):

The probability that a given person has none of the diseases, is $$\left(1-\frac{1}{100}\right)^5=\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^5$$

So the probability that all $500$ people don't have a disease is:
$$\left(\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^5\right)^{500}=\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{2500}$$
Hence the probability that at least one person has one of the five diseases is:
$$1-\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{2500}$$

Comment: Does this assume that one person cannot have more than one disease? My question is assuming that a person can only have one of the five diseases or not have a disease at all. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why you have $5$ in  the denominator? It should be 100.

Answer (score 1):

For this, it is easiest to consider the opposite: what's the probability that *noone* has any of these diseases?

Let's start with one disease: what's the probability that, out of 500 people, nobody has it?  That's 
$$\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{500}\approx 0.00657$$
which is a pretty small number.  But we've got five of these diseases floating around!  So it'll be that to the fifth power:
$$\left(\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{500}\right)^5=\left(\frac{99}{100}\right)^{2500} \approx 1.224\times10^{-11}$$
Which is a very tiny number - it's about 1 in 80 billion.

The probability that at least one person has one of these diseases is thus the complement of that, which is $1 - that$, or 0.99999999998775... ish.

---

Your comment to the other answer mentioned that these diseases are supposed to be *mutually exclusive* - that if a person has one of the diseases, then he's known to not have the others.  This is different from *independence*, which is what we assumed: the probability that a given person is diseased is $5/100=1/20=0.05$ in your assumption, and under ours it's $1-(99/100)^5\approx 0.049$.  This gives a final calculation of

$$\left(\frac{19}{20}\right)^{500}\approx7.207\times10^{-12}$$

or about 1 in 137 billion.  The probability that at least one person is sick is thus slightly higher.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful answer!